# How to repeat each line of a file, from the Linux command line?

Tags: linux, text-manipulation

How to make a file like:

```
one
two
three
...
```

into:

```
one one
two two 
three three
...
```

I'm thinking this must be possible with one simple Linux command.  If my editor had block selections or macros I could do it easily.  I'm using Geany right now.  Maybe I need to switch editors again, or find a Geany plugin.

Comment: I ended up installing SlickEdit (the original "E" editor) and recorded a macro to cut/paste the current line twice, skip to the next line, then hold down Ctrl+F12.

If I don't end up buying SlickEdit, I'll keep an eye on these other answers for future reference, tnx.

Answer (score 3):

You need the `paste` command:

```
$ cat > file
one
two
three
four
...
$ paste file file
one     one
two     two
three   three
four    four
...     ...
$
```

Comment: Careful that by default `paste` will use tabs as delimiters, you can override this with the `-d` option: `paste -d ' ' file file > outputfile`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat t
ccc
ddd
aaa
bbb

$ perl -p -i -e 's/.*/$& $&/' t

$ cat t
ccc ccc
ddd ddd
aaa aaa
bbb bbb
```

Comment: I played with your answer a little bit, this seems to work too: `sed 's/.*/& &/' t`